# How to access a NAMED part of array from PHP simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml-parsing

Ok so here is my XML that I have to work with..

```
 <ALL_STOCK>
  <SINGLE_ITEM>
   <SKU>1234</SKU>
   <USER_DEFINED NAME="Brand" TYPE="LIST" />
   <USER_DEFINED NAME="Theme" TYPE="LIST" />
   <USER_DEFINED NAME="Colour" TYPE="LIST" />Black</USER_DEFINED>
  </SINGLE_ITEM>
  <SINGLE_ITEM>
   <SKU>5678</SKU>
   <USER_DEFINED NAME="Brand" TYPE="LIST" />
   <USER_DEFINED NAME="Theme" TYPE="LIST" />
   <USER_DEFINED NAME="Colour" TYPE="LIST" />Red</USER_DEFINED>
  </SINGLE_ITEM>
 </ALL_STOCK>
```

Here is my PHP Code simplified..

```
$extractedxml = simplexml_load_string($result);
 foreach ($extractedxml as $eachproduct):
  echo $eachproduct->SKU;
  echo $eachproduct->USER_DEFINED['Colour'];
 endforeach;
```

I am trying to echo the SKU & Colour of each product. I can easily access the SKU and the above code works for that. How do I access an object based on its 'NAME' parameter?
If I just use

```
      echo $eachproduct->USER_DEFINED;
```

I get returned the value from the first `USER_DEFINED` entry in this case `Brand` I don't want to access it via a index number as these could change through the loop? Many thanks in advance!

More info:

Here is the output from a single products' `var_dump($each_product);`

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[56]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=2)
      'NAME' => string 'Brand' (length=5)
      'TYPE' => string 'TEXT' (length=4)

    object(SimpleXMLElement)[58]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=2)
          'NAME' => string 'Theme' (length=5)
          'TYPE' => string 'LIST' (length=4)

    object(SimpleXMLElement)[59]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=2)
          'NAME' => string 'Colour' (length=6)
          'TYPE' => string 'LIST' (length=4)
           string '"Black"' (length=5)
```

Comment: `var_dump($extractedxml)` and it should be clear...

Comment: Have tried this, I will `var_dump($eachproduct->USER_DEFINED);` above for you if this can help. My knowledge doesn't advise how to achieve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) like this:

```
foreach ( $extractedxml as $eachproduct ) {
    $colour = $eachproduct->xpath('USER_DEFINED[@NAME="Colour"]')[0];

    // returns actual value of SimpleXMLElement Object
    echo (string) $colour;
}
```

Also remove errors from XML:

```
<USER_DEFINED NAME="Colour" TYPE="LIST" >Black</USER_DEFINED>
```